# In VSCode, why the args in launch.json cannot be correctly passed to the integrated terminal?

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code on a Windows PC, SSH to a Linux machine, and run python script on the Linux machine. It seems the arguments in the launch.json file cannot be passed correctly to the integrated terminal, at least the behaviour is inconsistent.

If below debug config was used:

```
{
      "name": "Python: current file",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": ["-c", "default.cfg", "-l", "DEBUG", "2>&1", "|", "tee", "-a", "testlog.txt"]
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests"
},
```

Display in terminal would be like this: (**unwanted \ came out and script cannot run**)

```
-c default.cfg -l DEBUG 2\>\&1 \| tee -a textlog.txt
```

If this config was used,

```
{
      "name": "Python: current file",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args": ["-c", "default.cfg", "-l", "DEBUG", ">", "testlog.txt"]
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests"
},
```

The display is correct, no unwanted \ comes out, and scripts are running ok:

```
 -c default.cfg -l DEBUG > testlog.txt
```

Can anyone tell me why `2>&1 |`  would cause trouble but a single `>` wouldn't? I do need the `2>&1` to work without any issue...

This issue was not there originally but after some VS Code update it came out. Unfortunately I cannot remember the exact version.

Comment: The results I got in the terminal seem different from yours, `DEBUG 2/^>/^&1 ^|`

Comment: Are you running VS Code on windows and SSHed to a Linux machine? It seems to be encoding issue, but I have check VS Code and linux encoding settings, both are utf8

Comment: It seems that VSC does not understand `2>&1` as valid redirection and therefore escapes that term, so that it is forced to be a parameter. If this is the case, I would report it as bug to Microsoft. As a short-term workaround, wrap the call to your Python program into a bash script.

Comment: @user1934428 I've submit it half past ago.

Comment: How did you configure SSH ?

Comment: @Philippe no specific config, just connected with a key. No other parameters/arguments were used with SSH.